# If G is a full 5-ary tree with 13 leaves, then the number of internal vertices is

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

If G is a full 5-ary tree with 13 leaves, then the number of internal vertices is

A. 5
B. 16
C. 15
D. 3

Comment: Could you please define what a "full $5$-ary tree" is? Additionally, please provide context for your question (i.e. where you encountered it, why you care about it) and your attempt/thoughts toward a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually solve this one just by trying to construct such a tree. Every internal vertex must have exactly $5$ children, so you start with a root and its $5$ children. Clearly that’s not enough leaves, so give one of those children $5$ children. If you stop there, you have $5+4=9$ leaves. That’s not enough: you need $4$ more. There are a couple of ways to get them, but either way will give you the answer to the question.